# Whatsapp folder location changed from internal storage

Tags: android, whatsapp, mobile-application

I have an status saver application. Due to folder location changed the status are not showing in status saver application.

what path can I use to get them?

`String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";`

Previous folder location was this...

anyone can help???

Comment: this problem should be only in android 11 right?

Comment: I have used this but didn't workout
```private static final File NORMSTATUS_DIRECTORY = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses");```

Comment: Yes i updated my android version recently from 10 to 11 and from there this issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

For Android 11:

```
String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";
```

For other versions:

```
String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";
```